# Secure django_language cookie in django removes it

Tags: django, cookies, django-cms

I'm trying to secure all my cookies. I found no way to secure the `django_language` cookie which is set by the `LanguageCookieMiddleware`. Django don't offers the opportunity to set a setting to `secure` this cookie and set it to `httponly`.

```
class CustomLanguageCookieMiddleware(LanguageCookieMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response = super(CustomLanguageCookieMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)
        language = get_language()
        max_age = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  # 10 years
        expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=max_age)
        print(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME)
        response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, language, expires=expires, secure=True, httponly=True)
        # also tried instead of the line above:
        # response.cookies[settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME]['httponly'] = 'True'
        # response.cookies[settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME]['secure'] = 'True'
        return response
```

With this "solution" I don't even get the `django_language` cookie. So trying to modify it just removes it...?!

*In case you're asking why I'm trying to secure a little poor language cookie: Mozilla likes secured cookies...*

Comment: Just a note that `LanguageCookieMiddleware` is not part of Django - looks like you're using django-cms. How are you testing this? If you use `secure` then the cookie will not be set in local development, because your local server probably isn't using HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah. Right. It's django-cms, added the tag now. Thx for this hint about the local development without https. But the `httponly` flag should work in development environment ?

Comment: httponly doesn't mean what you think it does - it just means that the cookie cannot be accessed by JavaScript. It has nothing to do with whether you are using HTTPS. The `secure` flag on the other had means the cookie can only be set over HTTPS.

Comment: So in my local dev environment the httponly flag should appear for this cookie. But the issue is that the cookie is not appearing... Maybe because of the secure flag. I'll try it later.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post looking for the same thing and the solution is almost there, I've just tweaked it a little bit:

```py
# middleware.py

from cms.middleware.language import LanguageCookieMiddleware
from django.conf import settings

class CustomLanguageCookieMiddleware(LanguageCookieMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response = super().process_response(request, response)

        cookie_name = settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME

        if cookie_name in response.cookies:

            if settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY:
                response.cookies[cookie_name]['httponly'] = 'True'

            if settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE:
                response.cookies[cookie_name]['secure'] = 'True'
        return response
```

I think it might not have appeared to be working if the language cookie has already been set. If it is set then it won't appear in the response, so clearing that out worked for me.